# Does Spring MVC cache bean files that are not loaded on start of the web app?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I'm just curious on if I am better off putting it in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/context.xml or in my src/main/resources/something.xml path.

Technically I do not need to load something.xml until a specific controller is called, but I also want to keep something.xml separate from context.xml because they are both pretty huge files... which may be bad if my application has to constantly load something.xml every time the controller is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you put in something.xml is also loaded at the start of your webapp as context.xml is. So it's not really important what you load in one or another xml. I'd advise you to split in as many files as you need your XMLs.

Comment: Even though they're in different directories? And that I did not specify something.xml in my web.xml file?

Comment: Sorry I thought you specified them in the web.xml. How do you load something.xml ?